# React - conditionally show certain prices based on an API value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In our API we have MANY 'dealer-name' values. "CATERPILLAR FINANCIAL SERVICES CORPORATION" and everything else.

I'm trying to do two things:

1. If any other product comes back with the dealer-name of CATERPILLAR FINANCIAL SERVICES CORPORATION, put the conversion rate to 1.32.
2. All other products will have a conversion rate of 0.74.

There's logic in place that has the rate pricing already setup :

```
export function formatPrice(
  price,
  lang,
  inclCurTxt?: boolean,
  currency?: string
) {
  let formattedPrice = price;

  const usaRate = 0.74;

  const currencyText = inclCurTxt ? " USD" : "";
    if (currency != null && currency === "US") {
      //USD
      formattedPrice =
        accounting.formatMoney(Number(price) * usaRate, "$", 0) + currencyText;
    } else {
      //CAD
      formattedPrice = accounting.formatMoney(price, "$", 0) + currencyText;
    }
  return formattedPrice;
```

I've written out an exportable getConversionRate function that goes through the logic I've explained at the top:

```
export function getConversionRate() {
  let usaRate = 0.74;
  if (isEnvironmentBFE()) {
    const catName = "CATERPILLAR FINANCIAL SERVICES CORPORATION";

    // If it contains Cat Financial products, make US rate 1.32.
    if (detailsHtml.dealerId === catName) {
      usaRate = 1.32;
    }
  }
}
```

I've imported the getConversionRate function into the file and placed some code into the rendered details of the product on the page, however it's not working:

```
<div className="price-wrap">
<img
   className="flagimg"
   src={Constants.IMAGES.FLAG_CA}
   alt="CDN $"/>
   <span className="data_price_cad">{getConversionRate(detailsHtml.itemPriceCA)}</span>
</div>
<div className="price-wrap">
 <img
   className="flagimg"
   src={Constants.IMAGES.FLAG_US}
   alt="US $"/>
   <span className="data_price_usd">{getConversionRate(detailsHtml.itemPriceUS)}</span></div>
```

Am I implementing the getConversionRate incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are calling function incorrectly? getConversionRate is not defined to accept any parameters whereas you are passing some parameter into rendered code. May be code needs a fix related to function arguments.